# Null Pointer Exception of MapView

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've been trying to find the cause of this error:

```
>07-13 23:44:06.715: E/AndroidRuntime(2932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 23:44:06.715: E/AndroidRuntime(2932): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-13 23:44:06.715: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
07-13 23:44:06.715: E/AndroidRuntime(2932):     at com.example.usignasync.MainActivity.runOverlaysAgain(MainActivity.java:141)
```

My aim is to reload some map overlays when the location of the GPS changes, so I have the GPS set up and `onLocationChanged()` called `runOverlaysAgain()`, however I can't call a function that uses `findViewById` outside of a class using `Activity`. This is because `onLocationChanged()` is in a class using `LocationListener` and `runOverlaysAgain()` is in a class using MapActivity. So basically `findViewById` can't be run from  `LocationListener`, how would I fix this? Below is `runOverlaysAgain()` and the second line is line 141 as mentioned in the error:

```
protected void runOverlaysAgain(){
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();    
    Log.d("A", Integer.toString(mapOverlays.size()));
    mapOverlays.clear();
        String latitude;
        String longitude;
        if(lastKnownLocation!=null){
        latitude =    GPSTracker.yourLocation.substring(3,GPSTracker.yourLocation.indexOf("Long"));
        longitude = GPSTracker.yourLocation.substring(GPSTracker.yourLocation.indexOf("Long")+4, GPSTracker.yourLocation.length());
        }
        else{
            latitude="92000";
            longitude ="92000";
        }
```

A lot of the re-declarations were just me trying to figure out what was going on, to no prevail. They can be removed and a similar error will be generated again. So there are two possible things I need, either how to fix this error or how to create mapOverlays outside of onCreate().

Here is the XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/readWebpage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="readWebpage"
    android:text="Load Webpage" >
</Button>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0IhkxetuKVA3ujGbdU8kltq8tCDodiOrV-92Low"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Example Text" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Looks like the resource R.id.mapview does not exist.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Comment: Could you post the layout xml please.

Comment: XML posted as requested. MapView is there and there are no errors caught in onCreate() which has very similar code to runOverlaysAgain() and does use mapView as well.

Comment: Quick update: I realised that `runOverlaysAgain()` can only be run inside the `MapActivity` class and not in `LocationListener`. How can I call this function so that it will not catch errors at `findViewById()`? Thanks.

Comment: @user1479585 Are you adding uses-library in your android manifest file?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya yes, I have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Comment: @user1479585 post your android manifest file.

Comment: Ok, so I haven't found the answer to this particular problem but I've decided to use a timer instead, so it will update anyway. Thanks anyway for trying.

Answer (score 0):

first of all give this permission

then in  res/layout/main.xml declare mapview in this manner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
/>
```

and then call the mapview in your main activoty like this

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Comment: I've added my XML above, sorry for the confusion. This answer doesn't help as I already have each of these elements. Thanks anyway.